# Using datasource to bind data to listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox, datasource

```
public static List<string> users=new List<string>();
...
ListBox1.DataSource = Class1.users;
```

I have a ListBox and I would like to fill it with values from a collection. I try this but the list just wont fill, what else do I need to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting the data source, you need to bind the data:

```
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

If you do not set the `ListBox.DisplayMember` property, the binding will use your objects `ToString()` method for the item text.  In your case, as you are using List, you do not need to set `DisplayMember`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do like this

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Class1.users;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

if not call it after assingning collection

Comment: There is no need to set those properties as it is a List<string>.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Data using the

```
public static List<string> users=new List<string>();
...
ListBox1.DataSource = Class1.users;
ListBox1.DataBind()
```